# Plots do not show up on browser IDE

Tags: r, plot, rstudio, rstudio-server

I'm using RStudio server on a CentOS machine and connecting to it from my windows laptop via browser.

When I connect server with MobaXTerm SSH console and run plots there it shows up in a window on my client machine. But when I do it on the browser IDE console, it does not show up in Plots tab there. There are no error messages or log entries. Rstudio version is 1.0.44 and R version is 3.3.1.

I tried `dev.off()` until null device, changing permissions of directories of default R packages.

Edit: Plots show up within the rmarkdown notebook too. My problem occurs in the console. Also, Plots dropdown menu at the top seems disabled, greyed-out.

Comment: Are you using a rmarkdown notebook?

Comment: I wasn't. I got the rmarkdown package, and plot seems to be working there. My problem occurs in the console.

Comment: Assign any plot as `p <- ...`. Then try `print(p)` or `plot(p)`.

Comment: @Christoph `p` or `print(p)` returns `NULL`. `plot(p)` says that I need finite xlim values.

Comment: Strange. Which OS do you use?

Comment: Chrome browser on Windows 7 connecting to Centos 6.6.